# Laravel 8 Migration "General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: php, laravel, migration, database-migration, laravel-8

I'm trying to create a migration on Laravel 8, Here's my table

```
class CreateProductVariationOrderTable extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('product_variation_order', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('product_variation_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->integer('quantity')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('product_variation_id')->references('id')->on('product_variations')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('product_variation_order');
    }
}
```

And When I run `php artisan migrate` I get this chunk of error : `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table` product_variation_order`add constraint`product_variation_order_order_id_foreign `foreign key (`order_id`) references` orders `(`id`) on delete cascade)`

⚠️ EDIT: Here's my `product_variation` migration file.

```
class CreateProductVariationsTable extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('product_variations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('price')->nullable();
            $table->integer('order')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('product_variations');
    }
}
```

Comment: is the id type in order table is integer?

Comment: Can you post your `product_variations` migration? The foreign key and the column they reference need to be of the exact same type

Comment: @brombeer yes, just added it underneath

Comment: Sorry, migration for your `orders` table too, please. Do the `orders` and `product_variations` tables exist when trying to create the foreign keys?

Comment: @brombeer I can leave you my github repo : https://github.com/rust-7/fore-api
All my migrations are in `app > database > migrations`, I think this is better since there are too many migrations

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The foreign key has to be the same type as the reference key.

In your orders table, you define id as `bigIncrements()` which is unsigned big integer.

In your product_variation_order table, you define order_id as unsigned integer.

So the two keys do not match. Generally you should use big integer because it allows your database to grow larger and space difference between integer and big integer isn't significant.

So change `order_id` as unsigned big integer.

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('order_id')->nullable();
```

Also for consistency, all keys should be `bigIncrements()` or `unsignedBigInteger()`, this will save you headache in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

product_variations:

```
class CreateProductVariationsTable extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('product_variations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('price')->nullable();
            $table->integer('order')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        });
    }

   /**
    * Reverse the migrations.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function down()
   {
       Schema::dropIfExists('product_variations');
   }
```

}

product_variation_order:

```
class CreateProductVariationOrderTable extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('product_variation_order', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigInteger('order_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->bigInteger('product_variation_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('quantity')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->foreign('order_id')->references('id')->on('orders')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('product_variation_id')->references('id')->on('product_variations')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('product_variation_order');
    }
```

}

Comment: Why should OP "_use this code_"? What was the problem? What did you change to make it work? A little explanation in your answer would be nice

Comment: I think there is a problem with the index(), he used in the migrations.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it is necessary to migrate first the table in which there is the primary key before the table which contains the foreign key. To migrate a specific table use :

```
php artisan migrate --path=/database/migrations/file_migration_name.php
```